# How to extract the MAC address of an interface from witthin a driver code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm new to Linux Kernel programming and driver programming. I'm working with madwifi drivers, on Linux with kernel version 2.6.32-37 and wish to extract the MAC address of an interface inside the driver code. I know this information supposed to be found in the *netdevice* structure fields, but not quite sure which one of them is the right one.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between the *dev an the *real?
2. Which one of them should I use? (they're both in use in different parts of the code and I don't understand when should I use the former and when the latter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-17-sect-3:

> unsigned char dev_addr[MAX_ADDR_LEN];
>
> Hardware (MAC) address length and device hardware addresses. The Ethernet address length is six octets (we are referring to the hardware ID of the interface board), and the broadcast address is made up of six 0xff octets; ether_setup arranges for these values to be correct. The device address, on the other hand, must be read from the interface board in a device-specific way, and the driver should copy it to dev_addr. The hardware address is used to generate correct Ethernet headers before the packet is handed over to the driver for transmission. The snull device doesn't use a physical interface, and it invents its own hardware address.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is code in a network driver to access/set MAC address.

There is even a callback defined in `net_device_ops`

```
.ndo_set_mac_address = netdev_set_mac_address
```

It is handled differently on each network device depending on HW registers architecture.
For example for Xilinx AXI MAC address is written to `net_device` structure and specific HW registers of network controller:

```
static void axienet_set_mac_address(struct net_device *ndev, void *address)
{
struct axienet_local *lp = netdev_priv(ndev);

if (address)
    memcpy(ndev->dev_addr, address, ETH_ALEN);
if (!is_valid_ether_addr(ndev->dev_addr))
    eth_random_addr(ndev->dev_addr);

/* Set up unicast MAC address filter set its mac address */
axienet_iow(lp, XAE_UAW0_OFFSET,
        (ndev->dev_addr[0]) |
        (ndev->dev_addr[1] << 8) |
        (ndev->dev_addr[2] << 16) |
        (ndev->dev_addr[3] << 24));
axienet_iow(lp, XAE_UAW1_OFFSET,
        (((axienet_ior(lp, XAE_UAW1_OFFSET)) &
          ~XAE_UAW1_UNICASTADDR_MASK) |
         (ndev->dev_addr[4] |
         (ndev->dev_addr[5] << 8))));
}
```

So once MAC address is set, commands like **ifconfig** don't get it from device driver accessing HW registers, but from `net_device` structure.